Expo - Can Expo Components be used in Existing React?
I have inherited a mobile app that was built with React Native using Expo. This app has some components that I would like to use in a website. The components do not require native things like a camera, accelerometer, etc. The website uses React and Redux. Can I use the Expo components in the website?

Umm, I think you can use them in ReactJs. In fact, I've done that, but you need to check all the imports of the components.
